# How to preserve system command key behaviors in emacs-mac

Tags: emacs-mac-port

I am exploring switching from Emacs for Mac OS X (that is, the official GNU Emacs, compiled for macOS: https://emacsformacosx.com ) to the emacs-mac port, Mitsuharu Yamamoto's version of emacs with additional support for macOS ( https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac/ ).

My reason for switching is to want better, more idiomatic Mac support, so I'd like to configure emacs-mac so that it uses the alt/option key for meta, and supports the as many as possible of the normal system keybindings for the command key? That is, I want to support CMD-S for save, CMD-C for copy, CMD-V for paste, CMD- for end of line, etc..

The closest I have come is this snippet, but this merely disables that CMD key rather than reproducing or revealing default Mac behaviors:

```
(let ((is-emacs-mac-by-yamamaoto
       (and (boundp 'mac-carbon-version-string)
            (string= window-system "mac"))))

  ;; let "alt/option" key work as META
  ;; (instead of acting as it usually does for text entry)
  (setq mac-option-modifier 'meta)

  ;; Disregard the "command" key entirely
  ;; (instead of using it for META)
  (setq mac-command-modifier nil)

  ;; let "command" key pass to system
  (setq mac-pass-command-to-system 't))
```